# method declaration not found, beginner

Tags: ios

Hello Im trying to run a process called `OnProcessClick` after a code that simply sorts through images and seem to get two errors I cannot seem to solve. One is the error that the method definition for `onProcessClick` cannot be found and the second problem was the error message of expected expression for the IB Action `OnProcessClick` command, any help would be appreciated. I included parts of the .m file

```
PixelValueFilter.m file (beginning of it)
- (IBAction)onProcessClick:(id)sender
{
@autoreleasepool
 NSString *patientPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data/source/%02d/.", _patient.patientIdx];   
NSArray *imagePathList = [[NSBundle mainBundle]        pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:patientPath];


end of the PixelValueFilter.m file
NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
                NSTimeInterval executionTimeB = [methodFinish              timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
NSLog(@"Total execution Time: %f", executionTimeB);
                });
            });//end async B
        });

    });//end async A

    }//end autoreleasepool


}@end




PixelValueFilter.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <OsiriXAPI/PluginFilter.h>
@interface PixelValueFilter : PluginFilter
{

}
- (long) filterImage:(NSString*) menuName;
- (IBAction)onProcessClick:(id)sender;
```

@end

Comment: Show us your .m and .h files (relevant code) and google your errors.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow kevin. please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to provide better quality questions and as @Zil said, without code is hard to quess whats wrong

Comment: Your image is not uploaded correctly, please fix that.

Comment: Hi, I guess my notifications are not working. I cannot post pictures so I included the code I am having trouble with

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code and the error log, which will be good for figuring out the exact issue.

Looking at your problem statement above, it seems that you are facing a problem related to the method declaration/definition.

Two ways you can create methods in iOS

1) Method triggered by the interface builder(IB) events will be preceded by IBAction as the return type of the function, seeing which the xib is able to find this method in IB.

```
 - (IBAction) anyMethod 
{  
    // method definition
}
```

2) Method declared and defined in .h and .m files and also are called by code these methods will be preceded return type either void/ any other.

```
 - (void) anyMethod 
{  
    // method definition
}
```

For any specific things please elaborate and provide code with your answer.

Comment: I added the code, please ignore the large spacing in the code lines, just a format error. Essentially the problem is that its telling there is nothing being expressed by the onprocesscommand

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with the of this points:

1.) A method named OnProcessClick is define in .h only. You'll have to implement the method in .m file. So that it matches your implementation.

2.) The problem is not with that method, it is with the one before it. You forgot to close the previous method with a closing curly brace.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have defined the OnProcessClick in both files but I am getting the error that I am not defining it.

Answer (score 0):

please check name of method name properly, i think their is miss match of method names.(OnProcessClick) expected (onprocessclick), or please share the code

Comment: I think my main problem is that its essentially me that I am not defining the onprocesscommand even though I included the code within it so not sure what to do.